# Delete PDO OOP Problems

Tags: php, html

Good day everyone.
I totally need your help.I am pretty new to oop & pdo and I am having problems with my delete function. The item will not be delete whenever I click the delete button. It seems like I can't call the id. I just don't know what to do. Please help me solve this problem.

Here is my code. 
For the class(codex):

```
    public function deleteData($id,$table)
{
    $q = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));

}
```

For the UI and the page where I call the id:

```
<?php 
include_once "../styles/header-menu-out.php"; 
include_once "dbconnection.php";


function __autoload($class){
include_once("../main/".$class.".php");}

$code = new codex("localhost","library_books","root","" );
$books = $code->showData("book_info");

if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
if($code->deleteData($_REQUEST['id'],"book_info")){

 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Book Information have been deleted.');
            window.location='bookDeleteUI.php';
            </script>"; 
}}


?>


    <html>
        <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/library_style.css"></head>
        <title>Book-A-Holic: Delete & Update Books</title>
        <body><br /><center>
        <div id="content"><div class="echoname"><br/><br/><b><h2>Book Settings</h2></b><br/></div>
            <table id="tablecolor" class="echoname" border="1">
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Author</td>
                <td>ISBN</td>
                <td>Publisher</td>
                <td>Language</td>
                <td>Genre</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Availability</td>
                <td>Queue</td>
                <td><center>Settings</center></td>


    <?php
                echo "<pre>";
                foreach ($books as $book) 
                    {   
                        echo "<tr>";
                        extract($book);
                        echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$title."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$author."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$isbn."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$publisher."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$language."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$genre."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$quantity."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$availability."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$queue."</td>";
                        ?>
                        <td><button class="btn"><a href="bookUpdateUI.php?update=$id" >Edit</a></button>
                            <button class="btn"><a href="bookDeleteUI.php?id=$id">Delete</a></button></td>
                        <?php echo "</td>";     

                    }       
                echo "</pre>";
    ?>

            </table><br />
        </div></center>
        </body> 
    </hmtl>


    <?php include_once "../styles/footer-admin.php"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've almost got it and well done on using PDO with parametized queries. The problem is that you're not outputting the $id through the php interpreter. You need to do this:

```
<button class="btn"><a href="bookDeleteUI.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id); ?>">Delete</a></button></td>
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Mackrodt! It worked but what is urlencode and what is it's use? and btw, if you don't mind answering another question.. why is my javascript not working(the "book has been deleted " prompt)? ..

Comment: `urlencode` is used to escape characters so that they may safely be used in a `$_GET` query, e.g. `&` becomes `%26` so that you do not begin a new `key=value` parameter unintentionally (see http://php.net/urlencode). You are missing a return statement in your `deleteData` function. You need to `return true;` if the record was deleted or `return false;` if it failed.

Comment: Thanks for helping and for the lecture. Appreciate everything sir.